# What is the proper syntax to alias a join that contains a subquery?

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to alias a JOIN that has a subquery.

```
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    (
     SELECT   FieldA, FieldB
     FROM Table1
     JOIN Table2
     ON Table1.WellId = Table2.WellId
    ) AS wi
        AS MProd

ON Units.RS_Unit_Name = RTRIM(wi.RS_POOL) + '-' + wi.RS_Field
```

I get incorrect syntax near 'AS'...

wi is the alias FieldA & FieldB; How do I alias the RIGHT OUTER JOIN?

My original code was:

```
RIGHT OUTER JOIN TABLE1
        AS MProd

ON Units.RS_Unit_Name = RTRIM(wi.RS_POOL) + '-' + wi.RS_Field
```

which worked fine.  I replaced TABLE1 with a subquery which I did in the code sample.  I just can't seem to figure out the proper syntax to set MProd as the alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line of code:

```
 AS wi AS MProd
```

This is not valid syntax. It can be `AS wi` or `AS MProd`, but *not* `AS wi AS MProd`.

**This is valid:**

```
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
( 
  SELECT FieldA, FieldB 
  FROM   Table1 
  JOIN   Table2 ON Table1.WellId = Table2.WellId 
) AS MProd
ON Units.RS_Unit_Name = RTRIM(MProd.RS_POOL) + '-' + MProd.RS_Field ...
```

**and so is this:**

```
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
( 
  SELECT FieldA, FieldB 
  FROM   Table1 
  JOIN   Table2 ON Table1.WellId = Table2.WellId 
) AS wi
ON Units.RS_Unit_Name = RTRIM(wi.RS_POOL) + '-' + wi.RS_Field ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.  Maybe I'm not asking the question correctly, or maybe I just confused....

In the code you provided (1st example) MProd is the alias for the sub-query  defined in within (...) therfore only contains FieldA & FieldB.   I don't see how MProd.RS_Field would exist in that scope. 

I MProd, along with an alias for the RIGHT OUTER JOIN and the fields contained in that (not shown).  

Thanks

Comment: Upon further review... I'm an idiot...  Staring at the seeing something that was not there,,, anyway  @Alan,  Thanks, that worked.

Comment: No problem glad to help. Seeing things that aren't there is common for me when I'm working too many hours ;)